# Como usar fadeIn() em addClass()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css3

Tenho 10 elementos com classe "hide", menos a primeira. Ao clicar em um botão eu removo o proximo hide e adiciono a classe "show", mas ao adiciona-la quero colocar um efeito de fadeIn(). É possivel?

Comment: Sim é possível.

Comment: Como @SilvioAndorinha ?

Comment: possível duplicata de [Ir para o próximo elemento com next e adicionar uma classe ao anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6573/ir-para-o-proximo-elemento-com-next-e-adicionar-uma-classe-ao-anterior)

Comment: pensando bem, acho que não é uma duplicata, pois aqui utiliza-se de `fadeIn()` e lá não, porém a ideia é a mesma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue Fiddle com o que você deseja: http://jsfiddle.net/hdg9p/1/

**HTML**

```
<div>A</div>
<div class="hide">B</div>
<div class="hide">C</div>
<div class="hide">D</div>
<div class="hide">E</div>
<div class="hide">F</div>
<div class="hide">G</div>
<div class="hide">H</div>
<div class="hide">I</div>
<div class="hide">J</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
    width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".hide").fadeIn(3000).removeClass("hide");
```

Comment: Opa, isso mesmo Tiago. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

É possível realizar tal efeito utilizando transition do css3. Ex:

CSS:

```
div {
  transition: 1.3s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hide{
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Seu javascript ficaria assim:

```
$(".hide").removeClass("hide");
```